# finite differences for PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am having trouble with this question, much appreciated if anyone can help?

a) for the 2nd order wave equation:

\begin{align} 
&\partial_{tt}u(x,t)-c^2\partial_{xx}u(x,t)=0 & (x,t) \in (0,1) \text{x}(0,T)\\
&u(x,0)=u_0(x)  &(x,t) \in (0,1) \text{x} \{0\}\\
&\partial_tu(x,0)=v_0(x)  &(x,t) \in(0,1) \text{x} \{0\} \\  
&u(0,t) = u(1,t)=0 & t \in (0,T)   \\
\end{align}
construct an explicit finite difference method of order 2 in both spatial and temporal components.

b)for the same problem construct an implicit method of order 2 in both spatial and temporal components.

c)when are the above implicit and explicit discretisations stable?

i know this is a lot to ask but i would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Finite-Difference, Time Domain](http://dsec.pku.edu.cn/~tlu/lecture%20notes/NMiP%20FDTD.pdf) scheme, which uses centered time and space differences.  You can scale your grid such that $c=1$.  I will illustrate for an explicit scheme only.  Here,

$$u_i^n = u(i \Delta x,n \Delta t)$$

where

$$u_i^{n+1} = r^2 (u_{i+1}^n -2u_{i}^n + u_{i-1}^n) +2 u_i^n - u_i^{n-1}$$
$$u_i^{n+1} = r^2 (u_{i+1}^n + u_{i-1}^n) +2(1-r^2) u_i^n - u_i^{n-1}$$

where $r = \Delta t/\Delta x$ is the propagation equation for $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,I-1,I\}$ and $n \in \{0,1,\ldots,N-1,N\}$.  You also need your boundary conditions.

$$u_0^n = u_I^n = 0$$

for all $n$, and initial conditions

$$u_i^0 = u_0(i \Delta x)$$

$$u_i^1 = u_i^0 + v_0(i \Delta x) \Delta t$$

This scheme is stable so long as $r \le 1$.

Comment: i was just going through this myself and on the first line of $U_{i}^{n+1}$ isnt it supposed to be $+2U_{i}^{n}$ from when you add it to the other side of the '='

Comment: @user54511: nice catch.

Comment: just did it for implicit and got: $$ (1+2r^2)U_{i+1}^{n+1}=r^2(U_{i+1}^{n+1}+U_{i-1}^{n+1})+2U_{i}^{n}-U_{i}^{n-1}  $$ and stable when $r \leq \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2}}$